# CSS: inline a <pre> tag

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML:

```html
<p>The following text <pre>is an inline preformat block</pre> and will not be parsed.</p>
```

I want it rendered as a single line, with a preformat block in the middle of the sentence.  However, it is rendering as three separate lines:

---

The following text

```
is an inline preformat block
```

and will not be parsed.

---

And what I want is for it all to be on one single line.  I have tried setting the style to use `display:inline`, but that only solves my problem halfway: no newline is introduced at the end of the pre block, but there is still one at the start.

As has been suggested elsewhere, I tried using `white-space:nowrap`, but it accomplishes absolutely nothing at all.

No solutions based on javascript or jquery, please.  I want to make sure the solution works on browsers which have scripting disabled.

Comment: Use a `span` (or some other inline element to begin with) and style it appropriately. Since it's invalid HTML to have a `pre` (block-level element) inside a `p`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution #1 using `<pre>` (not recommended):**
You can use the following code, but the `<p>` element is a little bit broken. If you want to avoid to affect all `<p>` elements, add `class` or `id` attribute to the `<p>` element.

```css
pre, p {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<p>The following text <pre>is an inline preformat block</pre> and will not be parsed.</p>
```

**Solution #2 using `<code>`:**
A better solution would be to replace the `<pre>` with `<code>`. The output looks the same like the solution using the `<pre>` element.

```html
<p>The following text <code>is an inline preformat block</code> and will not be parsed.</p>
```

**Solution #3 using `<span>`:**
If you want to define the element yourself you can use the following:

```css
p span {
  font-family:monospace;
}
```

```html
<p>The following text <span>is an inline preformat block</span> and will not be parsed.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a span tag, and design that with css?

```
<p>The following text <span>is an inline preformat block</span> and will not be parsed.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<code>` though. See [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_code.asp).